# HTML Selection - Javascript "this.value" null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just made a post about this, and I thought I had got it working, but now I have run into another issue.

I have this snippet of Javascript:

```
function slideTo(target){
    var targetPosition = $(target).offset().top;
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetPosition}, 'slow');
}
</script>
```

Then I have this further down my page.

```
<select onChange="slideTo(this.value)">
        <option value="blank">blank</option>
        <option value="test">TestPi</option>
        <option value="banana">BananaPie</option>
        <option value="chicken">ChickenPie</option>
</select>
```

I have my console open in Firefox, and when I click on an option, it is throwing me this error.

```
TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is null
```

Please help.
Also, sorry if this is a duplicate. I had a quick look, and couldn't see anything that seemed relevant, but that may have just been my wording.

Comment: I assume you want to get the elements by their ids and, in your case, you are missing the `#` .. so you should do `var targetPosition = $("#" + jQuery(this).val()).offset().top;` . You con't need to pass the value as the parameter since you can get it from inside your function by using `jQuery(this).val()`

Comment: @Mindastic When you call a function using `onchange=slideTo()`, the element isn't passed as `this`.

Comment: Yup, you are right @Barmar. I was thinking about binding the event handler with jQuery. I am going to edit my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Well, i can't edit the comment now :(.

Comment: @Mindastic Why don't you post an actual answer?

Comment: @Barmar because the question owner already fixed the problem and posted his solution below.

Comment: But if you think you have a better solution, you can post that

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I am an idiot.

I needed to add #'s to the beginning of all my values.

```
<select onChange="slideTo(this.value)">
        <option value="#blank">blank</option>
        <option value="#test">TestPi</option>
        <option value="#banana">BananaPie</option>
        <option value="#chicken">ChickenPie</option>
</select>
```

This fixed my issue. :)

Comment: Why would you do it like that when a simple change in your script can handle that for you. Do this instead   `var targetPosition = $("#" + target).offset().top;`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing the `value` of a particular option element, you may change your selector from:

```
var targetPosition = $(target).offset().top;
```

To this:

```
var targetPosition = $('option[value=' + target + ']').offset().top;
```